# Cannot resolve System.Drawing.Printing

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to display a list of installed printers on the local computer using the method described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx) ...

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace SandBox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i]);        
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is on the `Using` statement, the 'Printing' namespace cannot be resolved.
Is there an additional reference I am missing?

UPDATE:  I have added references to `System.Drawing` & `System.Printing` but this does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to use the `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace, you must reference the assembly `System.Drawing.dll`

Comment: I am, `System.Drawing` resolves fine, but it is only when I try to use the `Printing` namespace that the code cannot resolve.  I have also tried adding `System.Printing`.

Comment: Triple check your references. Are you sure this is the right project? Are you sure you are not targeting Framework 1.1?

Comment: My project targets .NET4.5 and it has a reference to `System.Drawing` v4.0.0.0 I'll see if there is a 4.5 version of this DLL

Comment: You were spot on with checking that the reference was added to the right project. I have 2 projects in my solution and had added it to the wrong one accidentally. Many thanks (facepalm)

Comment: This happens me evey single day, so I'm used to this situation :)

Answer (score 6):

In `.Net Core` and `.Net Standard`, `System.Drawing.Printing` can be installed via nuget `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack